# yarn workspace has problem with private npm registry

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying `yarn workspaces` with modules that have private dependencies - so that there's a line like this specified in `.npmrc`:

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=this-is-some-fake-token
```

Token is obviously different. So when I run `yarn` from inside that module it grabs private modules just fine, however when I try to run it from the workspaces root, it fails with the error that it cannot find given private module on npm registry (but of course it can't - it probably shouldn't even be looking there):

```
error Couldn't find package "@namespace/module@1.1.4" required by "one-of-workspaces@0.0.1" on the "npm" registry.
```

Obviously in this case yarn doesn't respect `.npmrc` that I've dropped in the workspaces root, but why? Or it is not even supposed to? And doesn't support private registries in workspaces mode?

Comment: Did you manage fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yarn will respect `.npmrc` from your home directory (not 100% sure about monorepo root).

What you are for sure missing in your `.npmrc` is the line that mentions that `@namespace` packages should be picked from GPR:

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=this-is-some-fake-token
@namespace:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```